# Sending a JSON to php server using Android

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to send a JSON to my server using a HTTP POST, but when i want to see if the data was sending well i can't see anything in my server, it´s like the server doesn´t recognize de json. I don't know if i'm doing something wrong in the way i send the json or in the way i receive an show the JSON in my php server..  Can someone please help me about what i'm doing? Thanks a lot

*My code in my php server:

```
  $json = $_POST["json"];

  $data= json_decode($json, true);

  echo $data;
```

*That´s my json:

```
MyJson {"HeartRate":["10.0","10.0","10.0","10.0","10.0","10.0","10.0"],"RespRate":["28.2","28.1","28.0","28.0","28.7","28.6","28.6"],"Temperature":["239","239","238","238","236","236","236"]}
```

*That's my code in Android for send the JSON:

```
 @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Long... params) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String[] fra = fr_array.toArray(new String[fr_array.size()]);
            String[] fca= fc_array.toArray(new String[fc_array.size()]);
            String[] ta= temp_array.toArray(new String[temp_array.size()]);

            StatsJson Sjson= new StatsJson(fra,fca,ta);
            String json = gson.toJson(Sjson);

            // System.out.println("Este es el json de frec resp " +fra); este no me muestra el array
            System.out.println("Los tres parametros juntos " +json);

           // InputStream resEntityPostStream = null;

            HttpParams parametros = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(parametros);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106:81/verjson.php");

            List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           // postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonObject.toString()));
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString())); //modificar aqui xsi

            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = null;
            try {
                entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String result = "";

            if(inputStream != null){
                result="Si funciono";

            }
            else{
                result = "Did not work!";

            }

            Log.d("RESULT", result);

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set the header I had a similar issue, setting the heade fix my issue

```
<?php
$json = $_POST["json"];
$data= json_decode($json, true);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;
```

Comment: Now i have:      try {
                se = new StringEntity(jsonp);
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: But now i don´t know how i get the $json = $_POST["json"]; in my server. I use something like php://input... That shows me the names of the json array... but doesn´t show me the values.... You know something about it?

Comment: Instead of `echo $data` try `print_r($data)` since data should be an array and not a string since you `json_decode` the json string.

Comment: Ok i´m gonna focus in my first code.. You put a header in the php code.. it is necessary that i put the same header to send the json in my android code too?